# Double/integer conversion with cpp11

Tags: c++, r, r-lib-cpp11

I hope you are well!

This is a code that I prepared and which crashes the R session (https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp11_wip/dev/gdb-debug-4.R). The issue is that the C++ function `cpp_get_fe_gnl_()` doesn't like the matrix `obsCluster`, which is a matrix of integers. If we cast it as integer in R, the R session crashes with a 'memory not mapped' message. If we pass it as a double with no cast, the function does nothing and returns an error of 'double vs integer'.

```r
# library(fixest2)
devtools::load_all()

# REPRODUCIBLE ERROR ---

# gravity_pois = fepois(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product + Year, trade)
# fixedEffects = fixef(gravity_pois)
#  *** caught segfault ***
# address 0x55cf901cb924, cause 'memory not mapped'

# Traceback:
#  1: .Call(`_fixest2_cpp_get_fe_gnl_`, as.integer(Q), as.integer(N),     sumFE, dumMat, as.integer(cluster_sizes), obsCluster)
#  2: cpp_get_fe_gnl(Q, N, S, dumMat, nbCluster, orderCluster)
#  3: fixef.fixest(gravity_pois)
#  4: fixef(gravity_pois)

# Possible actions:
# 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
# 2: normal R exit
# 3: exit R without saving workspace
# 4: exit R saving workspace
```

This seems to be related to an integer overflow that returns negative  numbers. The question is why https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp11_wip/src/05_01_misc_helpers.cpp#L590-L591 and the corresponding loop https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp11_wip/src/05_01_misc_helpers.cpp#L593-L626 would introduce negative values. I created an issue for this https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/issues/53.

If I see what the function does line by line, we have

```
# the problem is in fixef.fixest function L882 Methods.R

# this is the same as to run fixef.fixest line by line
# lines 924-1079 that do not apply for this case

gravity_pois = fepois(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product + Year, trade)

object <- gravity_pois
notes <- getFixest_notes()
sorted <- TRUE
nthreads <- getFixest_nthreads()
fixef.tol <- 1e-5
fixef.iter <- 10000
S <- object$sumFE
family <- object$family
fixef_names <- object$fixef_vars
fixef_id <- object$fixef_id
Q <- length(fixef_id)
N <- length(S)
id_dummies_vect <- list()
for (i in 1:Q) id_dummies_vect[[i]] <- as.vector(fixef_id[[i]])
is_ref_approx <- FALSE
isSlope <- FALSE
dumMat <- matrix(unlist(id_dummies_vect), N, Q) - 1
orderCluster <- matrix(unlist(lapply(id_dummies_vect, order)), N, Q) - 1
nbCluster <- sapply(fixef_id, max)

# check the data types
print(paste("Q", class(Q)))
print(paste("N", class(N)))
print(paste("S", class(S)))
print(paste("dumMat", class(dumMat)))
print(paste("nbCluster", class(nbCluster)))
print(paste("orderCluster", class(orderCluster)))

# ERROR 1 ----

# THIS IS THE LINE THAT BREAKS FIXEF()
fixef_values <- cpp_get_fe_gnl(Q, N, S, dumMat, nbCluster, orderCluster)

# ERROR MESSAGE:
#
# OK L570OK L5954
# 0
# OK L612OK L6321
# 
#  *** caught segfault ***
# address 0x5623b3cd0df0, cause 'memory not mapped'
# 
# Traceback:
#  1: .Call(`_fixest2_cpp_get_fe_gnl_`, as.integer(Q), as.integer(N),     sumFE, as.integer(dumMat), as.integer(cluster_sizes), as.integer(obsCluster))
#  2: cpp_get_fe_gnl(Q, N, S, dumMat, nbCluster, orderCluster)
# 
# Possible actions:
# 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
# 2: normal R exit
# 3: exit R without saving workspace
# 4: exit R saving workspace

# NOW WE TRY TO STORE THE MATRICES AS INTEGER-TYPE
storage.mode(dumMat) <- "integer"
storage.mode(orderCluster) <- "integer"

# THE FUNCTION BREAKS AGAIN
# fixef_values <- cpp_get_fe_gnl(Q, N, S, dumMat, nbCluster, orderCluster)

# ERROR MESSAGE:
#
# OK L570OK L5954
# 0
# OK L612OK L6321
#
#  *** caught segfault ***
# address 0x56144c29706c, cause 'memory not mapped'
#
# Traceback:
#  1: .Call(`_fixest2_cpp_get_fe_gnl_`, as.integer(Q), as.integer(N), sumFE, as.integer(dumMat), as.integer(cluster_sizes), as.integer(obsCluster))
#  2: cpp_get_fe_gnl(Q, N, S, dumMat, nbCluster, orderCluster)
#
# Possible actions:
# 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
# 2: normal R exit
# 3: exit R without saving workspace
# 4: exit R saving workspace
```

To run it, and make the R session crash, I would need this "recipe" to follow the exact same steps I used:

1. Clone the project

```
git clone --depth 1 -b cpp11_wip --single-branch git@github.com:pachadotdev/fixest2.git
```

2. Open the fixest2 project in RStudio and press CTRL+SHIFT+B to install
3. Run the previous example

I also opened an issue for this problem: https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/issues/52.

The C++ code is this (https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp11_wip/src/05_01_misc_helpers.cpp#L540)

```
[[cpp11::register]] list cpp_get_fe_gnl_(int Q,
                                        int N,
                                        writable::doubles sumFE,
                                        writable::integers_matrix<> dumMat,
                                        writable::integers cluster_sizes,
                                        writable::integers_matrix<> obsCluster)
{
    // This function returns a list of the cluster coefficients for each cluster
    // dumMat: the matrix of cluster ID for each observation, with cpp index style
    // Q, N: nber of clusters / obs
    // cluster_sizes: vector of the number of cases per cluster
    // obsCluster: the integer vector that is equal to order(dum[[g]])
    // RETURN:
    // a list for each cluster of the cluster coefficient value
    // + the last element is the number of clusters that have been set as references (nb_ref)
    // => much optimized version May 2019

    int iter = 0, iterMax = 10000;
    int iter_loop = 0, iterMax_loop = 10000;

    // Creation of the indices to put all the cluster values into a single vector
    int nb_coef = 0;
    std::vector<int> nb_ref(Q); // nb_ref takes the nb of elements set as ref

    for (int q = 0; q < Q; q++)
    {
        // the total number of clusters (eg if c1: man/woman and c2: 10 countries: total of 12 cases)
        nb_coef += cluster_sizes[q];
    }

    cout << "OK L570";

    std::vector<double> cluster_values(nb_coef);

    // index of the cluster
    std::vector<int*> pindex_cluster(Q);
    std::vector<int> index_cluster(nb_coef);

    for (int i = 0; i < nb_coef; i++)
    {
        index_cluster[i] += i;
    }

    pindex_cluster[0] = index_cluster.data();
    for (int q = 1; q < Q; q++)
    {
        pindex_cluster[q] = pindex_cluster[q - 1] + cluster_sizes[q - 1];
    }

    // Now we create the vector of observations for each cluster
    // we need a starting and an end vector as well

    std::vector<int> start_cluster(nb_coef);
    std::vector<int> end_cluster(nb_coef);

    cout << "OK L595";

    int index;
    int k;

    cout << Q;
    cout << "\n";

    for (int q = 0; q < Q; q++)
    {
        cout << q;
        cout << "\n";
        // table cluster: nber of elements for each cluster class
        writable::integers tableCluster;
        tableCluster.push_back(cluster_sizes[q]);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            // cout << cluster_sizes[q];
            k = dumMat(i, q);
            tableCluster[k] += 1; // the number of obs per case
        }

        cout << "OK L612";

        // now creation of the start/end vectors
        for (int k = 0; k < cluster_sizes[q]; k++)
        {
            int *pindex = pindex_cluster[q];
            index = pindex[k];
            // index = start(q) + k;
            if (k == 0)
            {
                start_cluster[index] = 0;
                end_cluster[index] = tableCluster[k];
            }
            else
            {
                start_cluster[index] = end_cluster[index - 1];
                end_cluster[index] = end_cluster[index - 1] + tableCluster[k];
            }
        }

        cout << "OK L632";
    }

    cout << "OK L635";
    
    // matrix of the clusters that have been computed
    writable::integers_matrix<> mat_done(N, Q);
    writable::integers rowsums(N);

    cout << "OK L639";

    // vector of elements to loop over
    writable::integers id2do(N);
    writable::integers id2do_next(N);
    int nb2do = N, nb2do_next = N;
    for (int i = 0; i < nb2do; i++)
    {
        id2do[i] = i;
        id2do_next[i] = i;
    }

    cout << "OK L658";

    // Other indices and variables
    int qui_max, obs;
    int rs, rs_max; // rs: row sum
    int id_cluster;
    double other_value;
    bool first;

    cout << "OK L667";

    //
    // THE MAIN LOOP
    //

    while (iter < iterMax)
    {
        iter++;

        // Finding the row where to put the 0s

        if (iter == 1)
        {
            // 1st iter, we select the first element
            qui_max = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // we find the row that has the maximum of items done

            qui_max = 0;
            rs_max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nb2do; i++)
            {
                obs = id2do[i];

                rs = rowsums[obs];

                if (rs == Q - 2)
                {
                    // if rs == Q-2 => its the maximum possible, no need to go further
                    qui_max = obs;
                    break;
                }
                else if (rs < Q && rs > rs_max)
                {
                    // this is to handle complicated cases with more than 3+ clusters
                    qui_max = obs;
                    rs_max = rs;
                }
                else if (qui_max == 0 && rs == 0)
                {
                    // used to initialize qui_max
                    qui_max = obs;
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "OK L716";

        // Putting the 0s, ie setting the references

        // the first element is spared
        first = true;
        for (int q = 0; q < Q; q++)
        {
            if (mat_done(qui_max, q) == 0)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    // we spare the first element
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // we set the cluster to 0
                    // 1) we find the cluster
                    id_cluster = dumMat(qui_max, q);
                    // 2) we get the index of the cluster vector
                    int *pindex = pindex_cluster[q];
                    index = pindex[id_cluster];
                    // 3) we set the cluster value to 0
                    cluster_values[index] = 0;
                    // 4) we update the mat_done matrix for the elements of this cluster
                    for (int i = start_cluster[index]; i < end_cluster[index]; i++)
                    {
                        obs = obsCluster(i, q);
                        mat_done(obs, q) = 1;
                        rowsums[obs]++;
                    }
                    // 5) => we save the information on which cluster was set as a reference
                    nb_ref[q]++;
                }
            }
        }

        // LOOP OF ALL OTHER UPDATES (CRITICAL)

        iter_loop = 0;
        while (iter_loop < iterMax_loop)
        {
            iter_loop++;

            R_CheckUserInterrupt();

            // Selection of indexes (new way) to be updated

            // initialisation of the observations to cover (before first loop the two are identical)
            if (iter_loop != 1)
            {
                nb2do = nb2do_next;
                for (int i = 0; i < nb2do; i++)
                {
                    id2do[i] += id2do_next[i];
                }
            }

            nb2do_next = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nb2do; i++)
            {
                // we compute the rowsum of the obs that still needs to be done
                obs = id2do[i];

                rs = rowsums[obs];

                if (rs < Q - 1)
                {
                    // you need to check it next time!
                    id2do_next[nb2do_next] = obs;
                    nb2do_next++;
                }
                else if (rs == Q - 1)
                {
                    // means: needs to be updated
                    int q;
                    for (q = 0; mat_done(obs, q) != 0; q++)
                    {
                        // selection of the q that is equal to 0
                    }

                    int *pindex = pindex_cluster[q];
                    int index_select = pindex[dumMat(obs, q)];

                    // Finding the value of the cluster coefficient
                    other_value = 0.0;
                    // Computing the sum of the other cluster values
                    // and finding the cluster to be updated (q_select)
                    for (int l = 0; l < Q; l++)
                    {
                        // we can loop over all q because cluster_values is initialized to 0
                        index = pindex_cluster[l][dumMat(obs, l)];
                        other_value += cluster_values[index];
                    }

                    // the index to update
                    cluster_values[index_select] += sumFE[obs] - other_value;

                    // Update of the mat_done
                    for (int j = start_cluster[index_select]; j < end_cluster[index_select]; j++)
                    {
                        obs = obsCluster(j, q);
                        mat_done(obs, q) = 1;
                        rowsums[obs]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (nb2do_next == nb2do)
                break;
        }

        // out of this loop:
        //  - nb2do == nb2do_next
        // - id2do == id2do_next

        // Check that everything is all right
        if (iter_loop == iterMax_loop)
        {
            Rprintf("Problem getting FE, maximum iterations reached (2nd order loop).");
        }

        // if no more obs to be covered
        if (nb2do_next == 0)
            break;
    }
    
    cout << "OK L843";

    if (iter == iterMax)
    {
        Rprintf("Problem getting FE, maximum iterations reached (1st order loop).");
    }

    // final formatting and save
    writable::list res(Q + 1);

    int *pindex;
    for (int q = 0; q < Q; q++)
    {
        writable::doubles quoi(cluster_sizes[q]);
        pindex = pindex_cluster[q];
        for (k = 0; k < cluster_sizes[q]; k++)
        {
            index = pindex[k];
            // index = start(q) + k;
            quoi[k] = cluster_values[index];
        }
        res[q] = quoi;
    }

    res[Q] = as_sexp(nb_ref);

    return res;
}
```

Which is called from R here https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp11_wip/R/Methods.R#L882.

My apologies about the lack of a MWE, this seems to be about R and C+ communication so the example needs context.

Best wishes,

Comment: Note:  In C++, if you are passing around a single `int`, you can change it with a cast (but you generally don't have to because `int`-to-`double` will be done for you), but if you're passing around an array, what you're telling the compiler to do is to treat the array of `int` as  an array of `double`s, not convert the values in the array to `double`s. Since `int`s are generally half the size of `double`s, two `int` are being "glued" together and used as though they are one `double` and the poor computer will shoot off the end of the array and into the unknown.

Comment: Since you got a memory error when you did this, this is probably the case you've run into.  But! Even if they are the same size, `int`s and `double`s are formatted differently, and most of the `int`s will not have the same value when viewed as `double`s. The array will typically appear to contain garbage values. Casting needs to be performed with great care.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why I got negative votes. I have a C++ book here next to me and I'm asking because I actually don't understand the error. At least your comment points me in the correct direction.

Comment: Downvotes could be the result of just about anything up to and including "I'm having a bad <expletive deleted>ing day." I don't know enough about R to tell if this contains a [mre], is a duplicate of an existing question (but it probably is. You can't be the first person to run into this), or how best to fix it (maybe copy the `int`s into a `double` array), so I'm keeping my fingers well away from the voting buttons.

Comment: You don't even show the C++ code and the example is certainly not minimal. I'm not cloning some git repository without knowing what it is or if I can trust the source.

Comment: I updated the example to show the C++ code, which is the exact C++ function that created the problem and where is it called on the R side. I wouldn't put malicious code hidden in a question, that would make me a very bad person.

Comment: I updated the post again to explain where an integer overflow occurs, and I included the links to the C++ parts of the code in the repo

Comment: "this seems to be about R and C+ communication" Do yourself a favor and use the Rcpp package and its data structures. A cpp function with an `Rcpp::IntegerMatrix` as argument will have no issues with the type conversion if it gets called with a numeric matrix on the R side. Also, I see stuff like `std::cout` which is a big no-no and wouldn't pass CRAN checks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must use cpp11 to use the vendoring option in my lab. The cout is just to print my trials.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpp11/vignettes/converting.html), cpp11 doesn't support implicit conversion and you need to do it explicitely on the R side. It appears, you have tried to do that and encountered issues. You'll need to solve those.